# Проблема с кодировкой символов

Tags: php

Есть файл - `index.php` в кодировке **UTF-8 без BOM**.
Он выводит шаблон с такой же кодировкой. Везде на сайте кодировка UTF-8.
Когда в скрипте `index.php` пишу русские символы, то он выводит знаки вопроса.

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. `charset` и в шаблоне, и в скрипте, и в `.htaccess` прописан `utf-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того, как Вы отредактировали файл убедитесь, что Вы сохраняете его в правильной кодировке

Comment: ну это  в коментарии можно написать.

Answer (score 2):

В природе в принципе не существует такого явления, как "файл в такой-то кодировке".

Файлы не имеют такой мета-информации, как кодировка содержимого, которую любой редактор мог бы прочитать и сделать соответствующие выводы. Кодировку надо каждый раз указывать заново. Отсюда делаем вывод, что если даже "в кодировке **UTF-8 без BOM**" файл был и сохранен изначально, то в какой кодировке его сохраняли потом, при добавлении русских букв - одна из неразрешимых загадок цивилизации.

Для ее разрешения надо не забывать каждый раз при редактировании использовать редактор, который понимает УТФ и проверять, что при сохранении указывается именно эта кодировка, а не какая-то другая.